# How do you get Solr Views to query Acquia Search?

Tags: views, search

I'm looking to build a set of sites which are all indexed by [Acquia Search](https://www.acquia.com/products-services/acquia-network/cloud-services/acquia-search) into a single index.

I also plan to build an umbrella site to help people discover content on the sites below. I was looking to the [Apace Solr Views module](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views) for this. How do I get this module to build views from the Acquia Search index?

Comment: From previous experience, I wouldn't use Acquia Search. You're better off going with something like [websolr](http://websolr.com/). Easier to use, more reliable, much cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

**Acquia search :**

A search service provided by acquia which in-turns uses the Apache Solr search inside. Currently they are updated their acquia search with Solr 3.5.

**Apace Solr Views module :**
Module when enabled converts the views query from a database query to apache solr search query.

While enabling the Apache Solr Views module it will look for the apache solr configured in the drupal system automatically.

Comment: So you're saying Apache Solr Views module will find Apache Solr configuration and query that index, regardless of where Solr is hosted?